# Airflow - local File doesn't exist while trying to copy to aws bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

I want to copy a json file to aws s3 bucket and below is my code where i pass the file contents via kwargs and I write the contents to another file and copy to S3 but i am getting the below error:

```
[2022-12-31 11:47:50,387] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'warning: Skipping file /home/airflow/temp_splunk_sla.json/. File does not exist.\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:50,736] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)\r
```

I created a dataframe and dumped it into a json file. then i passed the content of the file into kwargs for copytos3 function. I created a new file with write mode temp_splunk _sla.json and I am getting the value for file key and writing into the file. But the above log says there is not file by that name, Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the source code

```
def copy_to_s3(kwargs):
    
    import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    import os
    import logging

    s3_path = kwargs['s3_path']

    splunk_run_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    filename = 'temp_splunk_sla.json'
    
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(kwargs.get('file',None))

    os.system('''aws s3 cp %s %s --recursive'''%(filename, s3_path))

    logging.info('''aws s3 cp %s %s --recursive'''%(filename, s3_path))
    
    return "Done"



def splunk_sla(**kwargs):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)

    print(df)

    df.to_json('/temp/temp.json',orient='records',lines=True)    

    splunk_run_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    s3_path = 's3://test-bucket/{env}/mpo/sla_{splunk_run_date}.json'.format(env=env,splunk_run_date=splunk_run_date)

    with open('/temp/temp.json', 'r') as fp:
        temp_file = fp.read()

    ComputePythonOperator(
                task_id='copy_s3',
                python_callable=copy_to_s3,
                op_kwargs={'file': temp_file,'s3_path':s3_path},
                provide_context=True,
                dag=kwargs['dag']
                ).execute({})

copy_s3_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='copy_s3_task',
    python_callable=splunk_sla,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

Thanks much

detailed Logs

```
[2022-12-31 11:47:44,322] {pod_launcher.py:132} INFO - Event: compute pods "computepython-f048731c" had an event of type "Pending"
[2022-12-31 11:47:45,644] {pod_launcher.py:122} INFO - Event: compute pods "computepython-f048731c" had an event of type "Pending" with message "None" and reason "PodInitializing"
[2022-12-31 11:47:46,993] {pod_launcher.py:122} INFO - Event: compute pods "computepython-f048731c" had an event of type "Pending" with message "None" and reason "PodInitializing"
[2022-12-31 11:47:48,339] {pod_launcher.py:122} INFO - Event: compute pods "computepython-f048731c" had an event of type "Pending" with message "None" and reason "PodInitializing"
[2022-12-31 11:47:49,707] {pod_launcher.py:132} INFO - Event: compute pods "computepython-f048731c" had an event of type "Succeeded"
[2022-12-31 11:47:50,014] {pod_launcher.py:206} INFO - Event with job id computepython-f048731c Succeeded
[2022-12-31 11:47:50,387] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'warning: Skipping file /home/airflow/temp_splunk_sla.json/. File does not exist.\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:50,736] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)\r                                                              \n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:51,151] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'INFO:root:aws s3 cp temp_splunk_sla.json s3://ngap--marketplace-allocation--prod--us-west-2/qa/raw/coverage/mpo-coverage-alerts/coverage_splunk_sla_2022-12-31.json --recursive\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:51,447] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'INFO:root:Done. Returned value was: Done\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:51,746] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'[]\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:52,060] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'{\'templates_dict\': None, \'file\': \'{"0":"test","1":1672272000000,"2":1672444800000,"3":1672435740000,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null}\\n{"0":"test1","1":1672272000000,"2":1672444800000,"3":1672430340000,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null}\\n{"0":"test2","1":1672272000000,"2":1672444800000,"3":1672437540000,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null}\\n{"0":"shipment","1":1672272000000,"2":1672444800000,"3":1672437540000,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null}\\n{"0":"test5","1":1672272000000,"2":1672444800000,"3":1672430340000,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null}\', \'s3_path\': \'s3://test-bucket/qa/mpo/sla_2022-12-31.json\'}\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:52,382] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'copy_to_s3\n'
[2022-12-31 11:47:52,733] {pod_launcher.py:100} INFO - b'Done\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the path of your file `temp_splunk_sla.json`, try to use the absolute path to save the file and to copy it to S3 using AWS CLI:

```py
def copy_to_s3(kwargs):
    
    import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    import os
    import logging

    s3_path = kwargs['s3_path']

    splunk_run_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    filename = '/temp/temp_splunk_sla.json'
    
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(kwargs.get('file',None))

    os.system('''aws s3 cp %s %s --recursive'''%(filename, s3_path))

    logging.info('''aws s3 cp %s %s --recursive'''%(filename, s3_path))
    
    return "Done"
```